# How do I make the Google Plus Badge responsive?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, google-plus

Currently, the Google Plus Badge automatically responds to changes in width: https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/badge/

Our new website design uses Bootstrap for responsive layout, how can we make this responsive?

Here is our current badge code:

```
<!-- Place this tag where you want the badge to render. -->
<div class="g-plus" data-width="230" data-href="//plus.google.com/102018846923934084444" data-rel="publisher"></div>

<!-- Place this tag after the last badge tag. -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
   var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
   po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
   var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
})();
</script>
```

As you can see, the default width is 230 pixels.  Kinda puzzled on how to do this cleanly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me. In case we have only one g-person-classed badge.

```
<div id="google-badge" style="width: 100%">
    <!-- Place this tag where you want the widget to render. -->
    <div class="g-person" data-href="//plus.google.com/104771303799616655833" data-rel="author" data-width="180"></div>
    <!-- Place this tag after the last widget tag. --><script type="text/javascript">
    window.___gcfg = {lang: 'de'};

    // just put this in here
    document.getElementsByClassName('g-person')[0].setAttribute('data-width', document.getElementById('google-badge').clientWidth);

    (function () {
        var po = document.createElement('script');
        po.type = 'text/javascript';
        po.async = true;
        po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    })();
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the widget, you could use the "static" badge option, which is basically just a link and an image. The widget code does not listen for updates to its attributes after it has rendered. Also, the height and width on the badge widget has constraints that likely would end up causing the badge to not render depending on how the width/heights were calculated in a responsive layout.

You would lose the dynamic functionality with a static badge like people being able to immediately add you to a circle without navigating away, but it does offer you more control over layout.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did...

Using twitter's bootstrap scaffolding classes, I created multiple badges that render depending on what "mode" the browser is in (e.g. desktop, tablet, or phone).

[Twitter Bootstrap Scaffolding](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html)

That worked!